# Array data from multiple ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

i have some code and request from multiple url, and result data is array , if i use `result.push(data)` the result will give `[[{Data1:a,Data2:b}],[{Data1:c,Data2:d}]]` how to merged data become array like `[{Data1:a,Data2:b},{Data1:c,Data2:d}]`

```
var url_api = [<?=$urlapi;?>];
var responses = [];

for(var i = 0; i < url_api.length; i++){
  getTarif(url_api[i]);
}

function getTarif(link){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: link,
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function () {
      alert('Unable to load url :'+link+', Incorrect path or invalid url');
    },
    success: function (data) {
       responses.push(data.data);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the spread syntax - `responses.push(...data.data);` - to add individual items to the `responses` arrays:

```
function getTarif(link){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: link,
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function () {
      alert('Unable to load url :'+link+', Incorrect path or invalid url');
    },
    success: function (data) {
       responses.push(...data.data);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: hey can i ask you something ? after i push the data and `console.log` its show empty array, but if i expand is showing 2 data . and if i call the array its not showing anything .

Comment: This is an async operation, so console.logging the results after `getTarif` shows you the current status (empty). When you you expand it, the console refreshes the result. Calling it is an sync operation that will get you the original empty array. Whatever you want to do with the data, add to a function, and call inside the success block. You should also learn about promises or async/await.

Comment: ```success: function (data) {
       responses.push(...data.data);
       fn(responses); // your logic
   }``` However, you should learn promises and async/await.